# PHP Function remove white color from background an pass back as file

Tags: php, gd

i have a question regarding the following function:

```
function transparent_background($img) 
{
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img); //or whatever loading function you need
    $colors= array("255","255","255");
    $remove = imagecolorallocate($img, $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $remove);
    //imagepng($img);
    return $img;
    imagedestroy($img);
}
```

The function requires a jpg image as input. for example:

```
$img=transparent_background("https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g%2BZj9gp8L.jpg")
```

If i directly output the $img to the browser with

```
imagepng($img)
```

I'll get a transparent background. But i want to pass the $img to another function and want to do some resize & merge with other pics. The Problem than is, that the function returns a jpeg and not a png so the whole transparency thing doesn't work. any ideas how it's possible to change the filetype without output to browser or file?

Here's another example which shows nearly the same problem:

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: image/png');
//$white = imagecolorresolve($img, 255, 255, 255); // resolve given palette entry
$colors= array("255","255","255");

$cutter=imagecreatefromjpeg('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81JIyreP8pL._SY450_.jpg');
$schneider = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61o2%2BaFFj-L._SX450_.jpg'); 
$base=imagecreatefromjpeg('http://bilder.hifi-forum.de/max/424786/weisses-testbild_124655.jpg');


$remove = imagecolorallocate($schneider, $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
imagecolortransparent($schneider, $remove);

$remove = imagecolorallocate($cutter, $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
imagecolortransparent($cutter, $remove);

$remove = imagecolorallocate($base, $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
imagecolortransparent($base, $remove);

imagecopy($base,$cutter,0, 5, 0, 0, imagesx($cutter),imagesy($cutter));
imagecopy($base,$schneider,250, 197, 0, 0, imagesx($schneider),imagesy($schneider));

imagepng($base);


?>
```

Same Problem.

Comment: Wait, multiple PHP errors spotted, such as using string in color array, scripts after `return` statement and missing quotes in `transparent_background()` call. Please double check.

Comment: Will You show the complete non-working code? If You do the resizing to a different target image than the `$img`, try calling `imagecolortransparent` on the new created image.

Comment: @RomanHocke: i ve added a working code with the same problem. you can see the transparency but the "schneider" transparency is over the cutter. Why?